# Was took or was taken

Tags: tense, past-participles

Which one is correct and why?

The decision was taken

Or

The decision was took

I am confused. Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took and taken are past form and past participle form of take respectively.
e.g.
Who took the necklace?
The necklace was taken by whom?